# Enterprise Library 6 RetryPolicyConfiguration Configuration Error

Tags: enterprise-library

I recently was attempting to configure an incremental retry strategy.  I followed the sample provided [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680900%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) and got the following error:

> Unrecognized attribute 'retryInterval'. Note that attribute names are
>   case-sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that from Enterprise Library 5 to 6, they renamed this parameter from **retryInterval** to **initialInterval**.  Hopefully this saves someone some time.